# Change the color of a UITableView grouped cells border

Tags: ios, swift2, uitableview

I've tried just about everything, but nothing seems to be working. I am trying to change the color of border of either the uitableview or the uitableViewCell, I can't really tell which one it is. Here is image to show what I am talking about, it's the default grey border. Tought to see but it's about 1px on top and bottom, and then divider line between the cells.

[image]

Here is what I have tried:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = Styles.blackColor()
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
```

The Styles is a class where I'm keeping all my visual settings, it's just returning UIColors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the color:

```
tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

If you want to simply remove it:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .None
```

If you want to make the separator full width:

```
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 0)
    if (cell.respondsToSelector("preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins")){
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to change the color of separator of table view.

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!